# Hide or block Sharepoint site and only let users use Powerapp

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created a simple Expense Powerapp connected to a Sharepointlist. Users within the organization can only see their own items in the Powerapp.

In order to allow them to enter a new item into the Powerapp, (besides sharing the App with them) I think i need to make them member of the Sharepointsite that contains this list? Is this right?

And if this is true, is there a way to block the list from them? They should not be able to see the expenseclaim items from their collegues.

Comment: You need to break inheritance on list item

Comment: https://collab365.community/sharepoint-item-permissions-using-flow-part-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a list, that is viewable via a powerapp. This is dynamic per user and they can only see their individual data. You need a way for them to add data to the list.

You can make a Powerapp form that populates the list. You can even have it send an approval request email.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form

Comment: They already add the data to the Sharepointlist by using the Powerapp. That is the way i would like them to do it. I just don't want them so see or be able to edit the Sharepoint list where all the items are stored.

Comment: Ok. I understand. what you need is item-level permissions: https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/